# Removing the text in Tumblr's controls bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a minimalist Tumblr theme with a clean controls bar, so I need to remove the text from it to make it look more clean.

Exactly like this:

[image]

Can this be done by hiding the elements through javascript?

1 message:

```
<span class="button-label">Message</span>
```

2 follow& unfollow:

```
<span class="button-label">Unfollow</span>

<span class="button-label">Follow</span>
```

3 dashboard:

```
<span class="button-label">Dashboard</span>
```

Or is there any another way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

using jquery you can hide `button-label` class `span` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span.button-label").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. <span class="button-label">Unfollow</span>
<br>
2. <span class="button-label">Follow</span>
```

if the elements you want to hide are inside an iframe

```
  $('#YOUR_IFRAME_ID').load(function(){ // wait for the iframe to load
    $(this).contents().find('span.button-label').hide(); // jump into the iframe find the elements required and hide them.
    });
```

Comment: Should I wrap it up with <script> and put it below the jquery script?

Comment: @Zack check the edited answer, if your the span elements you want to hide are inside an iframe then use the code snippet that is commented

Comment: It is a bit more tricky than the code you have written because the tumblr controls are delivered in an iframe. You can manipulate them but you have to write a bit more code I am afraid. Edit, you do have the correct code in your script but you commented it out?

Comment: @lharby if tmblr controls are delivered in an iframe please check the commented part of my answer. Place your iframe id in `$('#YOUR_IFRAME_ID').load(function(){` and run your test.

Comment: Yes it's correct, I was confused as to why it was commented out. But that code should work.

Comment: @lharby i am sorry the way i wrote it could be missed, i edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a really quick solution, you will need only 2 lines of code inside CSS. This will make the iframe element invisible.

```
.tmblr-iframe{

    display:none;
}
```